# a simple question about mixed effects and interactions

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

Suppose I have the following model written in **lme4**-like formula syntax:

`Outcome = year + categorical_variable + year : categorical variable + (year | group)`,

where `categorical variable` is a three level variable: `'x'`, `'y'`, and `'z'`.

In this case, the coefficient for `year` in the output is for the baseline level of the categorical variable (in this case `'x'`).

Now my question is, would the random effect only be random effect in relation to the mean of `'x'` or the mean of year with relation to `'x'`, `'y'`, and `'z'`?

Answer (score 2):

Let's first write the model conditional on the random effects in a mathematical formulation, i.e., $$\begin{eqnarray}
\texttt{Outcome}_{ij} & = &\beta_0 + \beta_1 \texttt{year}_{ij} + \beta_2 \texttt{Dy}_i + \beta_3 \texttt{Dz}_i + \beta_4 \{\texttt{year}_{ij} \times \texttt{Dy}_i\} + \beta_5 \{\texttt{year}_{ij} \times \texttt{Dz}_i\} +\\
&&b_{i0} + b_{i1} \texttt{year}_{ij} + \varepsilon_{ij},
\end{eqnarray}$$ $\texttt{Dy}_i$ is the dummy variable for level `'y'`, $\texttt{Dz}_i$ the dummy variable for level `'z'`, $b_{i0}$ is the random intercepts, and $b_{i1}$ the random slopes for $\texttt{year}_{ij}$.

If you write the model for level `'x'`, you get:

$$\texttt{Outcome}_{ij} = (\beta_0 + b_{i0}) + (\beta_1 + b_{i1}) \texttt{year}_{ij} + \varepsilon_{ij},$$

and for level `'y'` you get:

$$\texttt{Outcome}_{ij} = (\beta_0 + \beta_2 \texttt{Dy}_i + b_{i0}) + (\beta_1 + \beta_4 \texttt{Dy}_i + b_{i1}) \texttt{year}_{ij} + \varepsilon_{ij},$$

and similarly for level `'z'`.

Hence, as you see, the random effects represent how subjects / sample units deviate from their *group* mean.

Comment: Thanks, I had a moment of self doubt while coding up a model.